# mysql order by query is not working inside the union

Tags: mysql

This is my query the query will show the user which id have 2 first and union another users except user id 2.

```
(SELECT account.accountid,account.accountname FROM account,entity WHERE entity.id =  account.accountid  AND entity.deleted=0 AND account.accountid = 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT account.accountid,account.accountname FROM account,entity WHERE entity.crmid =  account.accountid  AND entity.deleted=0 AND account.accountid NOT IN(2) ORDER BY account.accountname )
```

The query is showing result very well but the order by is not working .
What i have to do here ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single query that orders first by `account.accountid = 2` and then by `account.accountname`

```
SELECT account.accountid,account.accountname 
FROM account,entity 
WHERE entity.id =  account.accountid  
AND entity.deleted=0 
order by case when account.accountid = 2 then 1 else 2 end,
         account.accountname
```